# scheme replace a symbol in a list with another symbol

Tags: scheme

I'm wondering how to replace a symbol in a list with another symbol. Here's what i come up with,

```
;; swap:  s1 s2 los -> los 
;; given a list of symbols and symbol1 symbol2 
;; return a list with all occurrences of s1 replaced with 
;; s2 and all occurrences of s2 replaced with s1

(define (swap s1 s2 1st)
   (cond 
      [(empty? 1st) empty]
      [(cons? 1st)
          (cond
              [(symbol=? (first 1st) s1) (swap s2 s1 (rest 1st))]
              [else (cons (first 1st)
                    (swap  s1 s2 (rest 1st)))])]))
```

tests;

(swap 'a 'd (list 'a 'b 'c 'd))=> list ('d 'b 'c 'a)

well, looks like my code only get rid of them instead of replacing them each other. Any suggestion what goes wrong here?

i'm thinking maybe,

```
[(symbol=? (first 1st) s1) (swap s2 s1 (rest 1st))]
```

should rewrite to

```
[(symbol=? (first 1st) s1) (cons s2 (rest 1st))]
```

this helps to replace 'a with 'd

but how to replace 'd with 'a in the else recursion process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you were close, but you forgot to `cons` if you found `s1`:

```
(define (swap s1 s2 1st)
  (cond 
    [(empty? 1st) empty]
    [(cons? 1st)
     (cond
       [(symbol=? (first 1st) s1) (cons s2 (swap s2 s1 (rest 1st)))] ; <--- cons added
       [else (cons (first 1st)
                   (swap s1 s2 (rest 1st)))])]))
```

Testing:

```
> (swap 'a 'd (list 'a 'b 'c 'd))
'(d b c a)
```